# Ansible dynamic variable resolution

Tags: variables, dynamic, ansible, resolution

Variable derived from another variable - how to get the result

I am using ansible version 2.7

I have the following vars file v1

```
envs:
  DEV:
    D1:
      Apps:
       App1:
         App_name: A1
       App2:
         App_name: A2
  SIT:
    S1:
      Apps:
       App1: 
         App_name: K1
       App1: 
         App_name: K2
```

I am passing `env_type` as DEV or SIT and `env_name` as corresponding D1 or S1.

my command line is

```
ansible-playbook test.yml -e "env_type='SIT' env_name='S1'"
```

I am expecting the code to return all the App_name fields for SIT S1 as a list, for further processing.

Can you please suggest how to structure the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
---
- hosts: local
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    envs:
      DEV:
        D1:
          Apps:
            App1:
              App_name: A1
            App2:
              App_name: A2
      SIT:
        S1:
          Apps:
            App1:
              App_name: K1
            App2:
              App_name: K2
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        app_list: '{{ envs[env_type][env_name]["Apps"].values() | map(attribute="App_name") | list}}'
```

Use the `values` method of the `Apps` object, `map` over them to get the attribute `App_name`, and then convert the result to a list.

You don't need to use the `set_fact` module, but I find it useful when I need to generate facts dynamically.